# Where do Folders Removed from the Finder Sidebar end up?

Tags: finder, sidebar

I just removed two document folders from my Sidebar in Finder, and now I can't find them! Any ideas on where they could have ended up?

Thanks!

Emma

Answer (score 2):

The folders/documents in the sidebar are just shortcuts to the given folders/documents.

So if you just removed them from the sidebar they still are where they've been.